# How Do I Install Stronghold 3 Gold Without A Key Code?

Tags: steam, stronghold-3

I'm a big fan of the Strongholds line, so picking up Stronghold 3 Gold was a no-brainer.

But then I tried to install it, and I discovered it required Steam. I still prefer boxes with DVDs and manuals. I'm not a fan of digital downloads, but I made the attempt anyway.

Well, everything was going fine until Steam required a CD-key - I didn't get one - on a *completely new, still shrink-wrapped, PC DVD.*

What options do I have, here?  How can I play this?

Comment: Bring it back to the store.  If you didn't get a cd key, that's returnable.

Comment: Depending on where you got it, you might be able to exchange it for another copy. This is apparently a [known issue](http://support.fireflyworlds.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/76/38/i-purchase-the-game-from-target-in-the-usa-and-the-code-card-is-blank) for copies sold by Target locations in the United States.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to legally play a game that requires steam, without the CD key.

If you purchased the game, new, return to the store with your receipt and demand an exchange for a copy that has a key or a refund. No matter where you are your consumer rights should at least cover you for that<sup>1</sup>.

If you purchased the game, second hand, you might have less rights. Regardless, all you can do is return to the person that sold it to you, and demand a key or a refund.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I assume, from the context of the question, that you have purchased the game within the last week. I expect you would need to return to the retailer as close to the purchase date as possible to claim not having included essential components. While warranty covers this inclusion, warranty for games can be different to other products. For example, in Australia most products come with a minimum 12 month warranty. Games come with only a minimum of 30 days.</sub>

Comment: I contacted Firefly Studios Support about this. They did the predictable thing - they "passed the buck" to Digital Tribe Games. I've been trying to get a response from Steam Support but all I've managed to come away with is the old "hamster-on-the-exercise-wheel" feeling. I think Firefly has lost a future customer.

Comment: @SpecterFan110557, you want to go **directly to the vendor**, as I previously stated. That would be the game shop, not steam, and definitely not Firefly. Ultimately, it is the game store that sold it.to you without a key. If steam or the developer were to hand out keys on their end based off that scenario, everybody would just claim "it wasn't in there", and there wouldn't be as much point in using them.

Comment: Was it shrink.wrapped **inside an original case**?

Comment: Yes it was shrink wrapped and it was in its original case. I purchased it from a vendor on Amazon and I have contacted them - or at least I have tried. I haven't heard anything yet.